# java3d simple way to translate object

Tags: java-3d

I am making my first program using Java3D. I have setup some transformGroups that I now need to move in calculated directions. When I looked this up, I found interpolators and alpha objects and waveforms and couldn't understand a word of it. I have done this in the past in OpenGL using simple vectors and frame refreshment. Is there a similar simple way in Java3d? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason you couldn't do it with vectors and frame refresh in Java3D as well.

A simple way would be to attach a behavior to the scenegraph with a WakeupOnElapsedFrames(0) condition, and then have it update the needed transform every frame.

As its simplest, that is was the interpolators are doing for you.  Once you get that working, it will probably make more sense as to how you could do it with interpolators.